# OS X Server VPN service starts httpd processes

Tags: apache-2.2, vpn, mac-osx, mac-osx-server

I'm using OS X Server 4, and when I enable its VPN service, two httpd processes start, which locks up port 80.

I run an Apache server separate from OS X Server, so when I enable VPN in OS X Server, I can't start up apache on port 80 anymore.

Is there a way to enable VPN in OS X Server without it locking port 80?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't give you a full answer, but I can at least give you an explanation of what's going on. OS X Server includes a number of web-based applications (webcal, wikis, profile manager, etc) in addition to the basic "Websites" service. It activates apache if *any* of the web-based services are running. So why is VPN a web-based app, you ask? Well, it isn't, but the accounts configuration service (which tells clients how to set up services for the server) is, and that starts as soon as you start any of the services that handles -- and VPN is one of those.

So, you turn on VPN, that turns on the accounts configuration service to tell clients how to set up the VPN service, and *that* turns on apache. Whee.

You can manually shut off the accounts configuration service (any any other web-based services that happen to be running) with `sudo webappctl stop -`, but that doesn't persist across restarts. There might be a way to tell the VPN service to quit registering with (& turning on) the accounts configuration service, but I don't know how.

Comment: Thanks, that makes a lot more sense now. I can just run that command in my apache start script.